# Как подключить huawei y9 к инструментам разработки google chrome на компьютере

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools

Зашел в google chrome на компьютере, открыл инструменты разработчика/настройки/remote devices там мое устройство не отображается. Переподключение кабеля не помогает(варианты передача фото, файлов и только зарядка), в любом варианте, устройство не появляется в панели crome. На телефоне так же активировал режим разработчика в настройках телефона и в google chrome. В chrome прокликал версию и появился дополнительный пункт настроек developer options, в нем пункт Tracing, в котором три пункта - default categories 118 out of 118 enabled, disabled-by-default-categories 0 out of 77 enabled, tracing mode - record until full. После всего этого пробовал переподключать кабель, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925992

Comment: у меня huawei, я пробовал установить adb драйвер по этой ссылке https://huaweiflash.com/huawei-y9-2018-usb-driver/ но он установился с ошибкой(запуск этого устройства не возможен). пробовал установить через adb driver installer 2.0, но он не видим мое устройство